# Logic on serializer fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to work out how to run some logic to get certain objects from within my serializer (or elsewhere).

I have the following:

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        Parent, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
        )


class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'children',
        )


class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ParentSerializer
    queryset = Parent.objects.all()


class ChildViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ChildSerializer
    queryset = Child.objects.all()
```

I would like to add a field to the `parent` response: `first_child` which is the first child alphabetically by `name` (this logic would be slightly more complex in reality, the largest value of the sum of multiple fields for example). I will also remove the `children` field in favor of this `first_child` field as the number of those will be too high to display in-line like this.

Comment: What's `Exercise` Model ?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo (copied from actual models). Fixed now.

Comment: Answer has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_representation` method

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance=instance)
        first_child = instance.children.order_by("name").first()
        data["first_child"] = ChildSerializer(first_child, read_only=True).data if first_child else None
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = Parent # change model name
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'children',
        )
```

Or, use `SerializerMethodField`:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer()
    first_child = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_first_child(self, instance):
        first_child = instance.children.order_by("name").first()
        if first_child:
             return ChildSerializer(first_child, read_only=True).data
        return None

    class Meta:
        model = Parent # Change model here
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'children',
            'first_child',
        )
```